# Java: Finding the Outermost Vertices of a Convex Polygon

Tags: java, geometry, 2d, trigonometry, convex-hull

### Original post:

I'm trying to find the outermost vertices of a convex polygon (with relation to a point **P** outside the polygon).  For now, I'm only concerned with rectangles (however, I'd like an algorithm that works with any convex polygon).

[image: Point Demonstration]

My plan is to construct a line from external point **P** to central point **C**.  From this *line of reference*, I will construct lines from point **P** to points **1**, **2**, **3** and **4**.  Since points **2** and **4** will have the largest (most positive) and smallest (most negative) angles from the *line of reference*, they will be identified as the *outermost vertices*.

Is this the best algorithm for the job?  How does one calculate angles from a reference angle (preferably in Java)?

---

### Update for clarification:

[image]

I've drawn the lines (*line of reference* in red).  As you can see, the line from **P** to **2** creates the largest angle on one side of the *line of reference*, while the line from **P** to **4** creates the largest angle of the other side.  Hence, these are the *outermost vertices*.

Comment: well, angle between two points A and B should be atan2(b.y,b.x) - atan2(a.y,a.x)

Comment: But simply taking the largest and second-largest angle might not solve the problem for all cases... I think.

Comment: Why not just consider farthest points from the line you draw from P to C?

Comment: I suppose that could work just as well.

Comment: "I'm trying to find the outermost vertices of a convex polygon (with relation to a point P outside the polygon)." - I don't understand.  Can you point to a reference?

Comment: No, not really.  I still don't know what you mean by "outermost."

Comment: @Peter actually the picture is not helpful to me.  When I look at the picture, I think vertex 3, but the commentary suggests the answer is vertices 2 and 4.  The concept is not clear to me.

Comment: @emory: Updated. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: @Peter thnx.  Now I understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
            // code simplified for demonstration
            double angleBetweenVertices;
            double maxAngleBetweenVertices;
            vectorA.setStartingPoint(outerPoint);
            vectorA.setTerminationPoint(polygonCenter);
            vectorB.setStartingPoint(outerPount);

            // For each vertex, calculate the angle between the outer point, the polygon's center and the vertex
            for (Point2D.Double vertex : vertices) {    
                vectorB.setTerminationPoint(vertex);
                double angleBetweenVertices = 
                    Math.toDegrees(
                        Math.atan2(
                            (vectorA.perpDotProduct(vectorB)),
                            (vectorA.dotProduct(vectorB)) 
                        )
                    );

                // Update the min and Max
                if (angleBetweenVertices >= maxAngleBetweenVertices) {
                    maxVertex = vertex;
                    maxAngleBetweenVertices = angleBetweenVertices;
                } else if (angleBetweenVertices <= minAngleBetweenVertices) {
                    minVertex = vertex;
                    minAngleBetweenVertices = angleBetweenVertices;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) problem.  You would be looking for a set of vertices (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>) around a polygon.  The methodology that would be applied is called "quick-hull", analogous to quicksort (in that we divide our region of points every time we step through).  It is also a safe assumption that *P* can be used as a mid-point between an arbitrary starting point and its parallel ending point, so you would get a convex hull around *P*.

It would take a while to produce some reliable Java to poke at (from my happenstance), but I think that the Wikipedia entry will give you a great starting point.

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't think this is very similar to the convex hull problem.  The boundaries of the shape are known, and I'm not using any Minkowski sums.  Additionally, **P** *is* the starting point for the calculations.  I'm looking for the *outermost vertices* with relation to external point **P**.  Therefore, the operation is iterative and requires no step-wise division.

Comment: The convex hull of the points 1,2,3,4 is known.  The convex hull of the points P,1,2,3,4 is not known.  I think the outermost points are the two points adjacent to P in the convex hull of P,1,2,3,4.  Notice 1 is not part of the convex hull of P,1,2,3,4.

Comment: Ah.  I understand now.  So is a convex hull algorithm the quickest way to solve this?

Comment: @Peter:  It would be a very quick way to solve it, yes; Quick-hull can achieve O(N*lg(N)) performance on average, with a worst-case of O(n^2) (highly unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

The use of trigonometry is extremely slow. You should use another angle comparison.

For an angle between two flat vectors:

cos(OA, OB) = (OA<sub>x</sub> * OB<sub>x</sub> + OA<sub>y</sub>* OB<sub>y</sub>) / sqrt((OA<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + OA<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup>)* (OB<sub>x</sub> <sup>2</sup> + OB<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup>))

I think, you can compare angles having cosines.